# Dynamic selection of rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic, subset, selection

I would like to built a user-defined function in R which allows the user to make a selection (subset) of a dataframe and then make some sort of a frequency/cross table. The selections can be quite elaborate with brackets and some AND's and OR's.

The input to the function is the selection criterium which then has to be applied to the dataframe. I want the selection criterium to be a string which is the input to a user-defined function, this allows users (who are not so good in R) to make selections and tables without having to bother with building dataframes themselves. I have tried several approaches, using `subset()`, `df[[var_name]]` etc, but I could not make them dynamic. The ideal would be something like the following:

```
# User makes a selection
selection <- '( age > 20 & gender == 'm' ) | age > 45'

# User applies it to the dataframe
subset(df , selection)
```

Or

```
df[ selection , ]
```

This however does not work, but maybe I'm missing something. Or maybe there's another approach how to do this. In databases for instance you can built a query as a string and then execute. Variables can be included in this querybuilding part to make it dynamic. Is something also possible in R?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you just use `dplyr::filter`? IMO its very intuitive - take a look at this:  http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html.

Comment: Why does it have to be a string input? Let the user supply an expression and use NSE like `subset` does.

Comment: Thanks Roland, very useful comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `subset`, then we need to `eval`uate

```
subset(df, eval(parse(text = selection)))
```

Or as @Roland suggested, instead of a string input, create an expression and then do the `eval`

```
selection <- expression(( age > 20 & gender == 'm' ) | age > 45)
subset(df, eval(selection))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(age = sample(10:60, 20, replace = TRUE),
  gender = sample(c('m', 'f'), 20, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `eval(parse())` without at least hinting that better alternatives are often available.

Comment: Thanks Akrun, it solves the problem. Roland's suggestion is also very good.